# Swift Parsing JSON

Tags: json, swift

I'm able to get JSON data because I can see it being printed out  using println. I can also print some individual keys. However I'm having a hard time converting it to string.

```
var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:     NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
    println(jsonResult.count) // works
    numberOfStations.text = String(jsonResult.count)
    //latitude.text = jsonResult["latitude"] as String
    //var result: String = jsonResult["latitude"] as String
    let latitudeData : AnyObject? = jsonResult["latitude"]
    let longitudeData: AnyObject? = jsonResult["longitude"]

latitude.text = latitudeData as NSString!   // Doesn't work
longitude.text = longitudeData as NSString! // Doesn't work
println("latitude --> \(latitudeData)")    // Works  prints it ok latitude ---> 40.30303
println("longitude --> \(longitudeData)")  //Works   prints it ok longitude ---> 37.20202
```

JSON similar to this

```
{
latitude: 34.0522342,
longitude: -118.2436849,
station_counts: {
 total: 247,
 fuels: {
     E85: {
       total: 0
   },
   ELEC: {
     total: 225,
     stations: {
       total: 55
     }
   },
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is attempting to convert the values by simply casting them to strings. You instead need to use a method that returns a string representation of the value. For example:

```
latitude.text = latitudeData!.description
```

Comment: Hi Kaelin, thanks for your insight, so I have to create a method called description that returns a string representation? In languages such as Java you can just call toString() ....

Comment: There is a read-only property called `description` that serves this purpose for Swift / Objective-C. (Sorry, I had incorrectly added function-call parens, which are not correct for accessing a property. I've edited my answer to fix that issue.)

Comment: Thank you! You are a genius!  How come I missed this one in the swift documentation? :)

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend depending on description() to parse json. This is how I'm parsing json in Swift (beta 4)

```
            //parse Episode Name
            if let jsonAsDict = responseObject as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            {
                if let array: AnyObject = jsonAsDict["episodes"]
                {
                    for item: AnyObject in array as [AnyObject]
                    {
                        //put episode name into array
                        self.episodeNames.append(item["name"] as String)
                    }
                }
            }
```

The json has this format:

```
            episodes: [
                {
                    name: "Episode Name 1"
                },
                {
                    name: "Episode Name2"
                }
            ]
```

self.episodeNames is declared as 'var episodeNames: [String]' in this example

Comment: I've up voted your answer WorkingDev as it helped me dig deeper into the JSON tree. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [**SwiftyJSON**](https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON), an open source library on GitHub that makes JSON processing in Swift real nice.

Comment: Hi I actually tried it and it makes Xcode unstable... what gives? What I did was I created a new swift file then copied over the code.

Comment: You can just drag `SwiftyJSON.swift` into your project, which probably has the same effect of you doing a copy/paste. Maybe you copied some weird characters, try using the file directly.

Comment: Yes i tried again, for some reason makes sourcekitservice unstable and it gets terminated...

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it hasn't yet been updated for beta 4 :(